# Unable to exit the while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, break

I tried to code a Singly Linked List program called "Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List" , but unable to exit the from the while loop.

I am able to compile and run the code successfully.I traced the program step by step more than four times , but unable to find the catch.

what I mean by "Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List"

Input: 17->15->8->12->10->5->4->1->7->6->NULL ; Output: 8->12->10->4->6->17->15->5->1->7->NULL

Input: 8->12->10->5->4->1->6->NULL ; Output: 8->12->10->4->6->5->1->NULL

If all numbers are even then do not change the list
Input: 8->12->10->NULL
Output: 8->12->10->NULL

If all numbers are odd then do not change the list
Input: 1->3->5->7->NULL
Output: 1->3->5->7->NULL

How I solved the problem :

temp :  to traverse the list.

evenPtr : pointer to even data node.

oddPtr : pointer to odd data node.

oddPtrStart : keep track of starting of the odd data node.

My function is below :

```
struct node *segregateEvenOddNodesSLL(struct node *temp)
{
    struct node *evenPtr,*oddPtr,*oddPtrStart,*head=NULL;

    head=temp;  

    while(1)
    {  
        if(((temp->data)%2)==0)   // even 
        {

            if(evenPtr==NULL)
            {
                head=temp;
                evenPtr=temp;
            }
            else
            {
                evenPtr->link=temp;
                evenPtr=temp;
            }  


        }

        else               // odd
        {
            if(oddPtr==NULL)
            {  
                oddPtrStart=temp;
                oddPtr=temp;
            }
            else
            {
                oddPtr->link=temp;
                oddPtr=temp;
            }



        }

        temp=temp->link;
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("\n Inside  While.... \n");

    }// end of while.

    if(evenPtr==NULL)
    { 
        return head;
    }
    else if(oddPtr==NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        oddPtr->link=NULL;
        evenPtr->link=oddPtrStart;

        return head;
    }


}
```

Call the function with head=segregateEvenOddNodesSLL(head);

As usual the structure of singly linked list is :

```
struct node 
{
int data;
struct node *link;
};
```

Comment: Extra (virtual) credit: implement the procedure without using more than one `if` / `else` construct or more than one looping construct.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following line:

```
struct node *evenPtr,*oddPtr,*oddPtrStart,*head=NULL;
```

that needs to be:

```
struct node *evenPtr=NULL,*oddPtr=NULL,*oddPtrStart=NULL,*head=NULL;
```

Here is how I found this:

1. The compiler should be giving you a warning that you forgot to initialize those values.
2. Stepping through, you should immediately notice that oddPtr and/or evenPtr are not null as soon as you get into the while loop.

Comment: But I am existing the while loop using temp pointer , not  using the rest of pointer.

Comment: You read the value of `evenPtr` and / or `oddPtr` (comparing them to `NULL`) before you get to the loop exit test.  Those variables are uninitialized, so they could contain anything.  They probably contain junk, but it is plausible that you are unlucky enough for one or both to contain the same value passed in as argument `temp`, or a pointer to one of the other nodes in the list, in which case the first iteration of your loop transforms the input list into a circular one.

Comment: Even if the uninitialized variables have meaningless values, it is clearly a bug to fail to initialize them.  Fix it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you are testing the values of variables `evenPtr` and `oddPtr` before initializing them.  It looks like you want to initialize each of them to `NULL` before entering the loop.

With that done, if this ...

```
    temp=temp->link;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        break;
    }
```

... never reaches the `break` to trigger a loop exit, and you never get a segmentation fault or other memory access error, then the most likely explanation is that your linked list is circular.  You could clue yourself in to that by printing the current node's `data` at each iteration.

Note, too, that your code after the loop is flawed: in the event that your list contains no even items, all the nodes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a list builder to make the initial, and even/odd lists. I have used a slight "cheat" - a list is most simply made in reverse order, so making the secondary even and odd lists, reverses them to the original order.

Another method could be to do a bubble sort on the original list, swapping the data field if 'odd' comes before 'even', but this answer tries to stick close to what OP does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node* add_node(struct node *list, int id) {
    struct node *n = malloc( sizeof (struct node) );
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->data = id;
    n->link = list;
    return n;
}

struct node *segregateEvenOddNodesSLL(struct node *temp) {
    struct node *odd=NULL,*even=NULL, *last = NULL;
    while(temp) {  
        if(((temp->data)%2)==0) {       // even
            even = add_node (even, temp->data);
            if (last == NULL)
                last = even;
        }
        else
            odd = add_node (odd, temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    if(even) {
        last->link = odd;            // append odd list
        return even;
    }
    return odd;
}

void show (struct node *list) {
    printf("List: ");
    while(list != NULL) {
        printf("%3d", list->data); 
        list = list->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void free_list(struct node *list) {
    struct node *tmp;
    while (list) {
        tmp = list->link;    
        free(list);
        list = tmp;
    }
}

void make_list(int *array, int elements) {
    struct node *list = NULL, *newlist;
    int i;
    printf("Array:");
    for (i=0; i<elements; i++) {
        printf ("%3d", array[i]);               // show unsorted array
        list = add_node(list, array[i]);        // make the linked list
    }
    printf("\n");
    newlist = segregateEvenOddNodesSLL(list);   // sort it
    show (newlist);                             // show sorted list
    printf ("\n");
    free_list (list);
    free_list (newlist);
}

int main(void) { 
    int data1[10] = { 17, 15, 8, 12, 10, 5, 4, 1, 7, 6 };
    int data2[7] = { 8, 12, 10, 5, 4, 1, 6 };
    int data3[3] = { 8, 12, 10 };
    int data4[4] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

    make_list(data1, 10);
    make_list(data2, 7);
    make_list(data3, 3);
    make_list(data4, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Array: 17 15  8 12 10  5  4  1  7  6
List:   8 12 10  4  6 17 15  5  1  7

Array:  8 12 10  5  4  1  6
List:   8 12 10  4  6  5  1

Array:  8 12 10
List:   8 12 10

Array:  1  3  5  7
List:   1  3  5  7
```